# jqGrid - "editable":"true" in JSON response for grid columns

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

**Problem 1**

I have the **column model** as

```
{name:'fname',index:'fname', width:50, align:"center", resizable:false},
{name:'lname',index:'lname', width:50, align:"center", resizable:false},
{name:'date',index:'date', width:50, align:"center", resizable:false, editable:true}
```

**If I change the jqGrid JSON response to include the names of the columns, the jqGrid data rows are empty with no data**

```
{
    "rows":[
        {
            "id":"1",           
            "cell":{                
                "fname":"S",
                "lname":"K",
                "date":"11/11/2011"
            }
        }
    ],
    "userdata":{"amount":3220,"tax":342,"total":3564,"name":"Totals:"}
}
```

**Problem 2 -- I tried adding "editable" within the cell definition (with or without the column names. *Here I'm showing the JSON structure with column names.*), jqGrid data rows are again empty**

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cell": {
                "fname": "S",
                "lname": "K",
                "date": [
                    {
                        "date": "11/11/2011",
                        "editable": "true"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "userdata": {
        "amount": 3220,
        "tax": 342,
        "total": 3564,
        "name": "Totals:"
    }
}
```

**The table cells are drawn but jqGrid is not picking up the JSON data.**

What am I doing wrong?

**jqGrid JSONReader**

```
jQuery("#editjqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "http://localhost/edit.json",
    datatype: "json",
    contentType: "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8",
    colNames:['fname','lname', 'date'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'fname',index:'fname', width:50, align:"center", resizable:false},
        {name:'lname',index:'lname', width:50, align:"center", resizable:false},
        {name:'date',index:'date', width:50, align:"center", resizable:false, editable:true}
    ],
    loadComplete: function (data) {     
        var item, i, l = data && data.rows.cell ? data.rows.cell.length : 0;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            item = data.rows.cell[i];           
            if (item.editable === "false") {
                $("#" + item).addClass("not-editable-cell");
            }
        }
    }

});
jQuery("#editjqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{add:false,del:false,edit:false,position:'right',minWidth:800,maxWidth:1405,minHeight:350,maxHeight:680});
```

**UPDATE: Adding inline editing options for a particular cell in JSON**

```
    {
        "rows": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "cell": {
                    "fname": "S",
                    "lname": "K",
                    "date": {
                        "value": "11/11/2011",
                        "editable": "true",
                        "edittype":"input",
                        "editoptions":{
                             "size":"20",
                             "maxlength":"30"
                        }
                    }
                    "emptype":{
                        "editable":"true",
                        "edittype":"select",
                        "editoptions":{
                            "option":"Full Time",
                            "option":"Part Time",
                            "option":"Hourly"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "userdata": {
            "amount": 3220,
            "tax": 342,
            "total": 3564,
            "name": "Totals:"
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2: Took out 'cell'**

```
    {
        "rows": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "fname": "S",
                "lname": "K",
                "date": {
                    "value": "11/11/2011",
                    "editable": "true",
                    "edittype":"input",
                    "editoptions":{
                        "size":"20",
                        "maxlength":"30"
                    }
                }
                "emptype":{
                    "editable":"true",
                    "edittype":"select",
                    "editoptions":{
                        "option":"Full Time",
                        "option":"Part Time",
                        "option":"Hourly"
                     }
                }
            }                
        ]
    }
```

**UPDATE 3: Added back 'cell' and modified the edittype and editoptions**

```
       {
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cell": {
                "fname": "S",
                "lname": "K",
                "date": {
                    "value": "11/11/2011",
                    "editable": "true",
                    "edittype":"text",
                    "editoptions":{
                         "size":"20",
                         "maxlength":"30"
                    }
                }
                "emptype":{
                    "editable":"true",
                    "edittype":"select",
                    "editoptions":{
                        "value":"Full Time",
                        "value":"Part Time",
                        "value":"Hourly"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

**loadComplete - 'not-editable-cell' not working**

```
loadComplete: function (data) {               
     var rowItem, x, l = data && data.rows ? data.rows.length : 0;           
     for (x = 0; x < l; x++) {  
    if (data.rows[x].cell.date.editable === "false") {
            $("#" + data.rows[x].id + "td[aria-describedby='editTimecard_date']").addClass("not-editable-cell");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The problem 1 is very easy. In the JSON you use `"cell"` and named properties together which is wrong for the default JSON reader. So you can fix the problem in two ways

**The first way**. You don't change the JSON format of data, but add `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}` parameter and `jsonmap` with `cell.` prefix in every column:

```
colModel: [
    {name: 'fname', index: 'fname', jsonmap: 'cell.fname', width: 70, align: "center", resizable: false},
    {name: 'lname', index: 'lname', jsonmap: 'cell.lname', width: 70, align: "center", resizable: false},
    {name: 'date',  index: 'date',  jsonmap: 'cell.date', width: 70, align: "center", resizable: false, editable: true}
],
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}
```

(see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11.htm)).

**The second way**. You use only `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}` and remove `cell` part from the  JSON data:

```
{
    "rows":[
        {
            "id":"1",           
            "fname":"S",
            "lname":"K",
            "date":"11/11/2011"
        }
    ],
    "userdata":{"amount":3220,"tax":342,"total":3564,"name":"Totals:"}
}
```

(see [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11_.htm)).

In your second part of the question I find very strange format of the `"date"` part of JSON data. Why the value of the property is array? Could it has more as one items? How the data should be displayed in the case? I think you should change format of the data.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with **`problem 1`**. **`Problem 2`** - my bad in json. I've updated it in the original post under the heading _"UPDATED"_. Basically, I want all inline edit options to be controlled in json.

Comment: @SK11: Should `"editable": "true"` from the JSON input be `"editable": true`? Is 'date' the only column which can be editable?

Comment: `"editable":"true"` or `"editable":true` makes no difference as far as jqgrid rendering is concerned. But yes, "true" is a string and true is a boolean value. No, any number of fields can be editable. **Example:** out of 10 columns, only 5 may be editable.

Comment: I've updated the JSON structure above to include another cell that can be editable.

Comment: @SK11: Your last suggestion of the JSON format is not better as before. Problem 1: I see no sense in the usage of `"cell"` property. Problem 2: You should better define *static* `jsonReader` which will work for every column (editable or not). Currently `lname` property can be read directly and to read values for the  `'date'` column one need read `value` property. The value of ``lname`` is string, the value of `date` is object, the value of `emptype` is `undefined`. Problem 3: You don't hold types of property in `colModel`: `editable` is boolean, `editoptions` for `emptype` is absolutly wrong.

Comment: **Problem 1** I took out `'cell"` property. **Problem 2** How do you define **static** `jsonReader`? I took out `jsonMap` from the column model and have it as `jsonReader:{repeatitems:false}`. **Problem 3** JSON structure is valid so I don't understand this.

Comment: @SK11: To **Problem 2**: `jsonReader:{repeatitems:false}` can read `"date":"11/11/2011"` (non-editable field), but not in the same time `"date":{value:"11/11/2011","editable": true, ...}`. So you should place `"editable": true, editoptions: {..}` out of the value of the `"date"` property of JSON. **To problem 3**: I mean that `edittype` has value `"text"` and not `"input"`, that `editoptions` of `edittype:"select"` should be in other format like `value:...`. If you hold jqGrid standard one can just use `$.extend` to set the option instead of analyzing and decoding of your input format.

Comment: I'm getting mixed responses from you. On one hand, I understand that it is possible to have `"editable"` and other inline editing options in json without having to define them in the `colModel`. On the other hand, I understand your response to say that it's not possible to control these options via json response. I'm confused.

Comment: If I place `"editable": true, editoptions: {..}` out of the `"date"` property, how can you control it for just 'date' ie **one particular cell**? I'm not trying to control editable feature for the entire row.

Comment: `loadComplete` is not adding the class `'not-editable-cell'` to the cell that has `editable:false`

Comment: Oleg -- I was able to make all form fields coming via JSON response work with `loadComplete()`. Can you pls help me with the JSON structure for `select`?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [jqGrid inline edit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing)

It show's an example how to conditionaly edit row's

code snippet:

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
  var data = jQuery('#grid_id').getRowData(id);
  if(data.editable == true) {  // <-- you may have to check this
    jQuery('#grid_id').editRow(id, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I'm looking for this. I'm trying to control the editable and other inline editing options in JSON.

Comment: don't you want to edit the `date` only when the json data contains `editable: true`?

Comment: see my updated code. maybe this will give you an beter idea what i mean

Comment: The problem is that I'm not getting the JSON data in the row so it's not worth trying this at this point.

Comment: sorry i meant more something like the second code block on this page http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data

Comment: actually, my JSON was wrong as "editable" was not specific to any cell. I've updated my JSON to make it specific to the date cell in the row.