# jqGrid editotype: 'select, formatter: 'select' not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JSON to retrieve the values for the select element.
my `colModel` is :

```js
{ name: 'position', editable: true, edittype: "select", formatter:'select',
    editoptions: {
        value: function() {
            var positions;
            $.ajax({
                url: "orthofixServices.asmx/GetPositionsList",
                data: "{}",
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    positions = data.d;
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
             });
            return positions;
        }
```

this is the response:

```json
{
    "d": {
        "21": "CAP Pos 1",
        "41": "CAP Pos 2",
        "42": "CAP Pos 3"
    }
}
```

And the row sent back from the server to bind the grid is

```json
{
    "d": {
        "page": 1,
        "total": 1,
        "records": 1,
        "rows": [
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Julio",
                "nameid": 0,
                "title": "Doctor",
                "npi": "123-123",
                "license": "licabc",
                "licstate": "NV",
                "position": "41",
                "us": false,
                "hrate": 0,
                "rrate": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

"position" is the field from the row that feeds the `select` element. After saving the row nothing shows on the grid. why? Should I save the key from the select as an `Int` or as a `String`. Does it matter? I tried both ways i never get to display anything on the grid for the select element. It should show: `"CAP Pos 42"`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `dataUrl` and `buildSelect` properties of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). Additionally you will have to set some properties of the `ajaxSelectOptions` option of the jqGrid.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8085692/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240517/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877286/315935) for examples of the usage.

Comment: I did exactly as you show on example 3rd. I do get results from the Database and the list gets populated. If i leave formatter; "select' after saving nothing shows on the grid, if i remove this ssetting it shows the key and not the value...I am saving the key in the database, I hope that is the way....please advice

Comment: I must say your example shows only the same value for "key" and "text" of the select. I did change the way the select is build by placing <option value=" + itemd[i].key + ">" + item.d[i].value + "</option>" Is there something else should be different?

Comment: @ManuelValle: You should be very careful if you want use select with the values other as option text. It will be important how you fill the grid and **when** you set the `value`. For example, you can extend the data returned from the server during filling of the grid with the response of `GetPositionsList`. Inside of `beforeProcessing` you can modify the `editoptions.value`. If you use editing you will have to do event more additional customization to send the *value* and not the text of selected option. So all have to be examined in details and full code which you use is required to see.

Comment: @ManuelValle: Even from design point of view I would recommend you don't use `formatter:'select'` if you need to load the value/text dynamically. The ids are **details of the server implementation** and the client should not really know about it. If you would have on the server side the name of the option you can easy modify the corresponding SQL queries to work with names instead of ids. Typically you use UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the name column so the searching by name is practically exactly so quickly as by id.

Comment: Do you have a working example. All I want is to have a select in the grid populated with value and text and been able to bind to the select and save new rows to the table. This should not be nothing complecated i am guessing....thanks

Comment: @ManuelValle: What I mean is very easy. You can just include `""CAP Pos 2""` instead of `"41"` as the `"position"` value and should not use `formatter:'select'`. The code will be easier and you will have less problems later if you decide to implement editing in the grid.

Comment: Well I really need to store the id and not the text on the database, it is a requirement. So I found a post where you load the values of the select in a variable and on loadcomplete you add those values to the select.....It is not ideal but it is working...thanks

Comment: @ManuelValle: You are welcome! You can "store the id and not the text" inside of the database, but still post back to the grid only the texts. I never wrote, that the usage of `formatter:'select'` is not possible. You will have to write more code only. On the other side the user will **never sees** the ids. So I *recommended* you only don't use `formatter:'select'` and just save your time. On the server side you should of cause hold ids and not only the texts in the corresponding tables.

Comment: @Oleg, I have the same problem when I use JQGrid. Now I have read your way of solving to that problem. You said that `Typically you use UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the name column'. But according to my requirement, the name column need to be allowed duplicate names. And then, only the ID column is allowed to force UNIQUE CONSTRAINT.

Comment: @Oleg, I need to load dropdownlist value/text dynamically.

Comment: @Oleg, please give me suggestion, if you don't like us to use `formatter:'select'`.

Comment: @Frank: You should describe the problem which you have more detailed. Why you don't want use `formatter:'select'`. How dynamic should be dropdownlist? Could be enough the loading of the value/text list at the loading of grid or the list must be more dynamic. Which data are in the JSON during filling of the grid: values or text? There are many options with some advantages and disadvantaged. It would be better if you described your requirements in details in new question. Moreover it's important to clear why you need to have values and not texts in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

The simple sad fact is that

```
formatter:'select',  editoptions: { value: function() { ...
```

is not implemented by jqGrid. The source code for `$.unformat.select` simply doesn't handle this case.
Just convert the data to an array and pass it in to the function through `value` to get the same effect.