# Drop Down in JQGrid

Tags: perl, jqgrid, dropdownbox

I am new to JQgrid and we are using Perl Catalyst to build the application.
I need to have a drop down for the Operating system field

Please find the code for JQgrid

```
<title>Server Details </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="[%         c.uri_for('/static/css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css') %]" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="[% c.uri_for('/static/plugins/jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css') %]" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="[% c.uri_for('/static/plugins/jqGrid/css/print-container.css') %]" />

<script src="[% c.uri_for('/static/plugins/jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js')%]" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="[% c.uri_for('/static/plugins/jqGrid/js/jquery.printElement.js')%]" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="[% c.uri_for('/static/plugins/jqGrid/js/printing.js')%]" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="[% c.uri_for('/static/plugins/jqGrid/js/export_to_excel.js')%]" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="[% c.uri_for('/static/plugins/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js') %]" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#list").jqGrid({ 
        url:"[% c.uri_for("server_details_json") %]",
        datatype:'json',
        mtype:'GET',
    colNames:['Server Id' , 'Host Name', 'IP Address','Operating System','Operating  System Version', 'Network Domain','Business Unit'],
        colModel:[ 

        {name:'server_id', index:'server_id', align:'centre',editable:false},
            {name:'server_name', index:'server_name', align:'left',editable:true},
            {name:'ip_address', index:'ip_address', align:'left',editable:true}, 
            {name:'operating_system', index:'operating_system', align:'left',editable:true, edittype: 'select', 
                searchoptions: {value:getOptionsList(),
                                sopt:['eq']}},

            {name:'operating_system_version', index:'operating_system_version', align:'left',editable:true},
            {name:'domain', index:'domain', align:'left',editable:true},
            {name:'business_unit', index:'business_unit', align:'left',editable:true},

 ],
pager:'#pager',
rowNum:10,
autowidth:true,
autoheight:true,
rowList:[10,20,30,1000000000000000000],
loadComplete: function() {
    $("option[value=1000000000000000000]").text('All');
},
sortname:'server_id',
sortorder:'asec',
shrinkToFit:true,
viewrecords:true,
gridview:true,
height:'auto',
editurl:"[% c.uri_for("postrow") %]",
caption:'Server List '
}); 

$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',{
        view:false, 
        del:true, 
        add:true, 
        edit:true, 
        search: true, 
        refresh: true,
        print:true 
        },

{height:250,width:500,reloadAfterSubmit:true}, // edit options
{height:480,reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // add options
{reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // del options
{} // search options
)
// setup grid print capability. Add print button to navigation bar and bind to click.
setPrintGrid('list','pager','Server Details');
setExcelGrid('list','pager','/tams/Server_Details_CSV','Server Details1');
}); 

</script>

 <script>
 function getOptionsList(){
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:"[% c.uri_for("OS_json") %]",
async:false,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
    options=data.value;
},
failure :function(xhr,status,msg) {
    alert("Unexpected error occured. !!!"+msg);
}
});
return options;
}
</script>

<body>
<table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table> 
<div id="pager"></div> 
</body>`
```

The Json Data is like this

```
[{"value":"Windows","id":"86"},{"value":"AIX","id":"87"}]
```

Can some one help me Thanks in advance for your precious time

Answer (score 1):

First of all you defined `searchoptions.value` for `operating_system` column which will be used during *searching* and not during editing. Moreover the property will work in Searching dialog only if you would add additional property `stype: "select"`. So you should add `editoptions: {value: getOptionsList() }` to have `<select>` during editing.

The format of `value` for `editoptions.value` and `searchoptions.value` can be either the string like

```
"86:Windows;87:AIX"
```

or an object like

```
{"86": "Windows", "87": "AIX"}
```

and not `[{"value":"Windows","id":"86"},{"value":"AIX","id":"87"}]` which you currently use.

You should change the code of `getOptionsList` to construct the corresponding results. By the way I prefer to use String form instead of Object form because it allows to specify the exact order of `<option>` elements in the `<select>`. The order of options in case of usage object form can be different in different web browsers.

I would recommend you to change your code so that you don't use synchronous Ajax request. Instead of that you can use `editoptions {dataUrl: "[% c.uri_for("OS_json") %]", buildSelect: function (data) {...}}`. You should additionally define `ajaxSelectOptions: {dataType: "json"}`. The callback function `buildSelect` get the server response (`data`) and it should return the HTML fragment of `<select>` with all `<option>` elements. You can find some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8085692/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240517/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877286/315935).

**UPDATED**: The code of `buildSelect` can be something like

```js
buildSelect: function (data) {
    var html = "<select>", length = data.length, i, item;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        item = data[i];
        html += '<option value=' + item.id + '>' + item.value + '</option>';
    }
    return html + "/<select>";
}
```

if you want that results of editing of the select will be sent as select id (like `86` for `"Windows"`) to the server (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/PravishJayasundar.htm)). If you want that server get the name (like `"Windows"`) then you need fill `value` of `<option>` elements using `value` property and ignore the `id` value:

```js
buildSelect: function (data) {
    var html = "<select>", length = data.length, i, item;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        item = data[i];
        html += '<option value=' + item.value + '>' + item.value + '</option>';
    }
    return html + "/<select>";
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/PravishJayasundar1.htm). You can use Fiddler, Developer Tools of IE or other free tools to trace the exact HTTP traffic during editing.

Comment: Hi Oleg,Thanks for your explanation will this Json Data work     [{"86":"Windows"},{"87":"AIX"}] I am not sure how to remove the square brackets from the json data in catalyst.

Comment: @PravishJayasundar: You are welcome! `[{"86":"Windows"},{"87":"AIX"}]` will **not** work. As I wrote the data can be *object* with properties like options in the select `{"86": "Windows", "87": "AIX"}` and not array of objects. Additionally the object form can not hold the order of items. If you use `dataUrl` the you can easy convert inside of `buildSelect` *any* server response to the HTML fragment.

Comment: ,thanks again for your prompt response this is driving me nuts....Is there a way to directly get the data from table? I am using MYSQL sorry to be a pain.

Comment: @PravishJayasundar: No, jqGrid is pure jQuery plugin and so it can't directly access MYSQL database. I'm not sure which problem you have currently. I described shortly many ways to solve your problem. The simplest one is modifying `success` callback to produce `"86:Windows;87:AIX"` from `[{"value":"Windows","id":"86"},{"value":"AIX","id":"87"}]` object. You need just write simple `for` loop.

Comment: @PravishJayasundar: Another (better way) is usage of `editoptions {dataUrl: "[% c.uri_for("OS_json") %]", buildSelect: function (data) {...}}` in `colModel` for `operating_system` column. You need add jqGrid option `ajaxSelectOptions: {dataType: "json"}` additionally. The callback function `buildSelect` is very simple too. You need convert the same input `data` (`[{"value":"Windows","id":"86"},{"value":"AIX","id":"87"}]`) to the string `<select><option value="86">Windows</option><option value="87">AIX</option></select>`. So I don't understand where you have the problem.

Comment: @PravishJayasundar: I appended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `colModel` must be like,

```
{ name: 'Decision', width: 200, editable: true, formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select',
editoptions: {
                        value: {
                            '1': 'Option 1',
                            '2': 'Option 2',
                            '3': 'Option 3'
                        }
               }
},
```

I guess, it must be `editoptions` instead of `searchoptions`.
Here is an [example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridPostLocalDataToServer.htm) grid, thanks to Oleg

Comment: Hi,When I hard code the values then with     editoption it is working fine but i need the data to be displayed from table.

Comment: Follow Oleg's solution and take time to check his links, his explanation is more deep and more clear than mine! :)

Comment: Thanks AthibaN, I am following is explanation...:-)Thanks for your help